# Python environmental factors that affect imports

Tags: python-2.7

I have a very odd issue that I don't even know how to begin debugging.

I am running a python package that, four days ago, ran with no issues.  Two days ago I started getting odd errors such as `a object does not have attribute tryClick` ("a" being my class).  The code for tryClick has not been touched in a week, long before this issue started.

Importing variables from one file to another has also been screwy.  For example:

```
my_var = None

class myClass(Base_Test):

    def myfunction(self):
        global my_var
        my_var = True
        return my_var
```

imports of `my_var` used to return `True` but now return `None`

The bizarre thing is that if I pull my package from our git repo onto a clean machine, set PYTHONPATH, and run the package, everything works fine!  I have clear the code out of my machine, re-pulled the code and run the package but still get these errors.

My conclusion is that this is environmental, but I don't know what it could be!  What kinds of environmental factors could cause this issue??

---

Not that this error adds much to my explanation, but it has been requested, so here you go

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\depot\external-access\gitfusion\MyShipRush\Selenium\WebShipping\selenium_error_report.py", line 35, in decorator
    value = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Selenium\WebShipping\Tests\MainForm\SampleCode_toGetStaleElementReferenceException_test.py", line 22, in test_Staleelementexception
    self.tryClick('#%s .service-row' % service_id)
AttributeError: 'a' object has no attribute 'tryClick'
```

More complete class example:

```
import unittest
import Shortcuts
from Utils import Base_Test
from LogUtils import logger

class a(Base_Test):

    def test_togetstaleelementexception(self):

        Shortcuts.open_settings(self)

        logger.debug("Selecting Service")
        Shortcuts.click_dd(self)
        service_id_elements = self.find_elements("#ServiceDropDown .row-holder")
        service_id = service_id_elements[1].get_attribute("id")
        self.tryClick('#%s .service-row' % service_id)
```

I can assure you `tryClick()` exists in `BaseTest`.  If I run this code on a clean machine, there are no errors.  If I run it on my machine, there are errors.  The code is exactly the same, as I've deleted and repulled all of my code in both places.

Comment: please provide a complete example demonstrating the error

Comment: `my_var` should be `None` after you import the module until you call `.myfunction()` method. Unrelated: avoid globals (use them sparingly), avoid returning values from methods that modify state inplace.

Comment: check that there are no multiple copies of the code (different versions of the same modules) in different directories that are in `sys.path`. Check `module_where_tryClick_is_defined.__file__`, to make sure that it has the expected path.

Comment: your indentation is off here. is it the same in your code or is that just stack? - ie your `self.tryClick()` is out side your `def test_togetstaleelementexception` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JFSebastian - your comment nailed it!

While there was only one reference to the `BaseTest` module in my package, there were two directories that held it on my machine.  Both dirs were in `sys.path` - when I moved my code I knew to add the new dir to PATH, but didn't think through the repercussions of leaving the old one.

I removed reference to the old one and everything works again.

Thank you!